# Como criar uma classe em java?

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber como se cria uma classe no `java`, como usar essa classe no programa principal e como fica a variável criada nessa classe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inicialmente é chamado o método main da classe principal (start do programa), mas nenhuma instância da classe (objeto) é criada apenas ao fazer-se isso.

Para ser criada uma instância da uma classe, é necessário chamar-se o construtor desta classe (se não houver um, o compilador criará um construtor sem parâmetros padrão).

Após a instanciação é possível atribuir valores aos atributos do objeto, ou então passá-los como parâmetros para o construtor e atribuí-los dentro do construtor.

Nesta atribuição deve-se ter certa cautela, pois dependendo da classe do objeto que está sendo utilizado (neste exemplo a classe principal), um erro de compilação vai ocorrer se houver uma tentativa de se violar as regras de visibilidade.

Os modificadores de atributos, construtores e métodos são: `protected`, pacote (também chamado de *default*, que é a ausência de modificador), `private` e `public`.

A única diferença de `protected` para pacote (ausência de modificador) é que `protected` permite que subclasses (classes herdeiras) de fora do pacote tenham acesso.

Mais detalhes nesta pergunta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

**Obs:** No Java 8, a palavra-chave "default" é um modificador válido para métodos de interfaces, e que em tal contexto não tem relação nenhuma com a visibilidade de pacote (default, ausência de modificador).

```
class Programa {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Conta minhaConta = new Conta();

    minhaConta.dono = "Duke";
    minhaConta.saldo = 1000.0;

    System.out.println("Saldo atual: " + minhaConta.saldo);
  }
}
```

Classe conta com seus métodos e atributos:

```
class Conta {
   double saldo;
   String dono;

   void saca(double quantidade) {
     double novoSaldo = this.saldo - quantidade; 
     this.saldo = novoSaldo;
   }
 }
```

Complementando o assunto de modificadores: Para garantirmos uma segurança maior e maior encapsulamento (dentre outras características) é necessário restringir o acesso as variáveis (geralmente usando modificadores de acesso `protected` e `private`) impossibilitando o acesso direto do atributo (verifique o nível de acesso de cada modificador), para prover o acesso é utilizado **Métodos acessores** `get` e `set`:

```
private double x; 

public double getX() { 
      return x; 
} 

public void setX(double x) { 
    this.x = x; 
}
```

Assim por exemplo é sempre possível fazer uma validação dos valores a serem atribuídos.

Comment: funciona como `struct`no c++ porém contém método  embutidos

Comment: Tem outras características que diferencia OO de java com os structs de C++/C, mas é possível armazenar ponteiros para funções dentro de structs.

Comment: Não entendi esta colocação: "Classe Principal (porque tem o método main), chama-se o construtor da classe, passando os atributos (por default não existe atributo no construtor padrão que é criado automaticamente) "

O programa pode ter diversas classes com métodos main, estas podem ser executadas através do comando "java" na linha de comando.

Acho que seria interessante rever esta explicação.

Comment: mas quando é necessário rodar o projeto como todo você deve manter uma unica classe com main tanto que quando você tenta rodar no netbeans por exemplo e exibido um pop-up de escolha de classes principais.

Comment: Você está confundindo atributos com parâmetros. Também está confundindo o método main com construtores. Não é verdade que a visibilidade protected é padrão. A sua explicação sobre atribuir valores em relação a visibilidade ficou confusa, desconexa e sem sentido. O campo saldo não existe. Além disso, você está estimulando e ensinando uma má prática de programação a principiantes sem advertir sobre isso com o acesso direto aos campos de uma classe a partir de uma outra, violando o encapsulamento. Gosto muito de você como usuário aqui do SOpt e não gosto de dar downvote, mas desculpe, -1.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Onde estou confundindo atributos com parâmetros? e método main com construtores? para que eu concerte entenda melhor.

Comment: "*Classe Principal (porque tem o método main), chama-se o construtor da classe*" - Isso não é muito claro, mas pode dar a entender que o construtor da classe principal é chamado, o que não é verdade. Ou então que o método main obrigatoriamente vai chamar um construtor, o que também não é verdade. Enfim, esclareça o texto neste ponto. / "*chama-se o construtor da classe, passando os atributos (por default não existe atributo no construtor padrão que é criado automaticamente)*" - Aqui seria parâmetros e não atributos.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Irei deixar meu texto mais claro, mas não tem nenhuma informação errada? (fui procurar as diferenças entre protected e default e adicionarei) não foi minha intenção que o texto fica-se confuso.

Comment: Bem, na verdade o default não é um modificador de visibilidade, e sim a ausência de um modificador de visibilidade. E para piorar ainda mais, no Java 8, a palavra-chave "default" é um modificador válido para métodos de interfaces, e que em tal contexto não tem relação nenhuma com a visibilidade default. Sei que devo estar parecendo ser muito chato com tudo isso, mas é que iniciantes na linguagem java tendem a confundir estes conceitos facilmente, então é importante que o texto seja muito preciso. E o texto do primeiro parágrafo continua confuso.

Comment: @VictorStafusa editei minha resposta.

Comment: Também editei o texto para esclarecer em cima do que você havia feito, e removi o downvote. Só não entendi essa parte: "*Nesta atribuição deve-se ter certa cautela, pois dependendo da localização do objeto que está editando propriedades (neste exemplo a classe principal) de outro objeto esta operação não será realizada.*"

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25254/discussion-between-ricardo-henrique-and-victor-stafusa).

Answer (score 4):

As classes que podem ser chamadas como principais para aplicações Java-SE são classes que servem como ponto de entrada/execução de sua publicação, estas classes são as que possuem o método público e estático `main`, este método espera receber um *array* de `String`s que representa os argumentos oferecidos quando a classe foi chamada com o comando Java pela linha de comando.

Mesmo que você utilize uma IDE para executar sua aplicação, a IDE irá chamar este método informando os parâmetros que podem ser passados pela tela de parametrização da execução.

No corpo do método `main` você pode referenciar variáveis estáticas de sua classe, instanciar a própria classe através de um de seus construtores, e em seguida referenciar suas variáveis se estas forem visíveis, o que irá depender de seu escopo. Você também poderá instanciar outras classes, manipular as variáveis visíveis e chamar seus métodos visíveis conforme o escopo.

@Rodolfo, do meu ponto de vista sua pergunta é muito ampla e pode vir a envolver diversos conhecimento relativos a construção de classes e pequenos programas em java.

Answer (score 3):

```java
class NomeDaClasse {

      // Atributo
      public int atributo;

      // Método construtor
      public NomeDaClasse() {
      }

      // Metodo
      public void metodo() {

      }
}
```

Para criar um instância da classe:

```java
NomeDaClasse objeto = new NomeDaClasse();
```

Comment: Lembrando que atributos públicos são quase sempre uma má prática de programação. E também que construtores não são métodos.

Answer (score 1):

```
class AlgumaCoisa 
{
   /* Alguma variável qualquer */
   bool ClasseLegal = true;

   int Arg1 = 0; //primeiro argumento
   int Arg2 = 0; //segundo argumento

   /* O método construtor deve ser o nome da classe */
   public AlgumaCoisa(int Argumento1, int Argumento2) //Pode remover os argumentos se quiser
   { Arg1 = Argumento1;
     Arg2 = Argumento2; }

   /* Propriedade somente leitura qualquer */
   public readonly int CodigoDaClasse()
   { return 20; }

   public int SomaDeles() { return Arg1 + Arg2; }
   public int MultDeles() { return Arg1 * Arg2; }
   public int DivsDeles() { return Arg1 / Arg2; }
   public int SubtDeles() { return Arg1 - Arg2; }
}
```

para declarar ela use:

```
AlgumaCoisa nomeAqui = new AlgumaCoisa(ValorDoArgumento1, ValorDoArgumento2)
```

Aqui vai um exemplo com essa classe:

```
AlgumaCoisa nomeAqui = new AlgumaCoisa(10, 10)
int Soma          = nomeAqui.SomaDeles(); // 20
int Multiplicação = nomeAqui.MultDeles(); // 100
int Divisão       = nomeAqui.DivsDeles(); // 1
int Subtração     = nomeAqui.SubtDeles(); // 0
```

Comment: `readonly` não é um modificador em java. O seu código não segue as convenções da linguagem java, e é importante segui-las porque esta é uma pergunta para iniciantes que estariam a aprender sobre este tipo de coisa. Construtores não são métodos, e isso é importante porque trata-se de uma informação falsa que está sempre sendo repetida por aí e neste tópico ela tende a ser absorvida por iniciantes na linguagem.  Além disso, o seu comentário "Pode remover os argumentos se quiser" só tenderá a confundir os iniciantes na linguagem. Odeio dar downvote, mas desculpe, -1.

Comment: É, eu não sou bom em Java, considero o Java uma linguagem comparável ao C#, pois então eu tenho uma noção que o Java aceita a sintaxe do C#, aceito seu voto e ele é bem-vindo, pois todos tem direito de opinar algo, vou procurar melhorar minha experiência em Java, nunca programei nada nisso, é um novo mundo para mim.